# Move a range of words to the end of the string

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have the following string:

```
"5  S comment=whatever Unspecific text fruit=apple animal=mouse sky=blue"
```

I need to move to end of the string, all that begin with `comment` to the word `text`.

The start is always be `comment=`  and the delimiter is always `fruit`. The value between `comment=`... and `fruit` delimiter is variable.

any suggestion?

Comment: Can there be more than one `comment=` and/or `fruit` in that string? Do you need that process for every line of a file, or just in a string stored in a shell variable? Can that string contain newline characters?

Comment: Yes, there may be many lines in the file. And only one field with comment= for each line. Also, the end of the string can be variable, this end could be  sky=blue or  raze=human, or whatever word, is unspecific.
and i using bash . 
Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

If that string is in a shell variable, and that shell is `zsh`, you can do:

```
string='5  S comment=whatever Unspecific text fruit=apple animal=mouse sky=blue'
new_string=${string/(#b)(comment=*)(fruit*)/$match[2] $match[1]}
```

If that shell is `ksh93`:

```
new_strong=${string//@(comment=*)@(fruit*)/\2 \1}
```

If that shell is a POSIX shell (like those two, `bash` or the `sh` of modern systems):

```
a=${string%%comment=*}
b=${string#"$a"}
b=${b%fruit*}
c=${string#"$a$b"}
new_string=$a$c$b
```

For each line of a file:

```
sed 's/\(comment=.*\)\(fruit.*\)/\2 \1/' < file
```

All three would match the part from the left-most `comment=` to the rightmost `fruit` if there were more than one per line/string.